# How to make my MTS Mblaze to be usable in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: networking, 14.04, internet

I had an online chat with MTS Customer Care and they say their device does not support Ubuntu 14.04 but only older versions. Does anybody know how to configure it to be usable in Ubuntu 14.04, because I strongly feel that they might be wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for me but it is not a permanent solution as I have to follow the below method each time to get stable connection.

- Open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>
- First stop service by typing

  `sudo service network-manager stop`
- Then plug net-setter & wait for 20-30 seconds.
- Then start service by typing

  `sudo service network-manager start`

But it is not a permanent solution as I have to follow above method each time to get stable connection.

Comment: my Mblaze is  getting detected as well as connected
i also get a valid ip on conection
but whenever i start my browser no internet connection still persist